# Make 12 with 1, 5, 19, 10

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

How can you make the number 12 with just the numbers 1,5,19,10?
You can only use each number once, and can only use subtraction addition multiplication and division.

Comment: Do we need to use each of 1,5,19,10 exactly once?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

It's certainly possible if

> the division operation is what is sometimes termed "integer division" (that is, ignoring remainders)

Since

> $19 \text{ div } 5 = 3$

So

> $10 + 19 \text{ div } 5 - 1 = 10 + 3 - 1 = 12$

---

#### A brute force of non-lateral-thinking evaluations...

If for each of the $4!=24$ permutations of the numbers [`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`] we take each of the $4^3=64$ three-wise Cartesian product of the four operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) [`p`, `q`, `r`] and arrange them in the sixteen (I think) ways:

```
A
A p B
A p B q C
(A p B) q C
A p (B q C)
A p B q C r D
(A p B) q C r D
A p (B q C) r D
A p B q (C r D)
(A p B) q (C r D)
(A p B q C) r D
A p (B q C r D)
((A p B) q C) r D
A p ((B q C) r D)
(A p (B q C)) r D
A p (B q (C r D))
```

Then (while we will have equivalents) we will cover all the possible ways to calculate a result without resorting to any lateral thinking approach. (Note that we do not need `B` or `C q D` and the like since the permutations and Cartesian product will rearrange to equivalents in terms of `A` or `A p B` and so on.

*Note: Please do comment if there are any I have missed! (I have not put the formula in terms of Catalan numbers, as I am not 100% on it myself)*

This gives only $4^3\times 4!\times 16 = 24,576$ evaluations to make, which makes it pretty easy for a computer to print any that are as close or closer to $12$ as any so far evaluated - as this Python 3 code does (I added an epsilon just to catch any floating point deviations):

```
from itertools import permutations, product
distance = 12
epsilon = 0.001
for A,B,C,D in permutations((1,5,10,19)):
    for p,q,r in product('+-*/', repeat=3):
            for s in ("{0}", "{0}{4}{1}", "{0}{4}{1}{5}{2}", "({0}{4}{1}){5}{2}", "{0}{4}({1}{5}{2})", "{0}{4}{1}{5}{2}{6}{3}","({0}{4}{1}){5}{2}{6}{3}","{0}{4}({1}{5}{2}){6}{3}","{0}{4}{1}{5}({2}{6}{3})","({0}{4}{1}){5}({2}{6}{3})","({0}{4}{1}{5}{2}){6}{3}","{0}{4}({1}{5}{2}{6}{3})","(({0}{4}{1}){5}{2}){6}{3}","{0}{4}(({1}{5}{2}){6}{3})","({0}{4}({1}{5}{2})){6}{3}","{0}{4}({1}{5}({2}{6}{3}))"):
                    e = s.format(A,B,C,D,p,q,r)
                    v = eval(e)
                    curDistance = abs(12 - v)
                    if curDistance - epsilon <= distance:
                            distance = curDistance
                            print(e, '=', v)
```

Which prints:

```
1 = 1
1+5 = 6
1+5+10 = 16
(1+5)+10 = 16
1+(5+10) = 16
1+5+10 = 16
(1+5)+10 = 16
1+(5+10) = 16
1+5+10 = 16
(1+5)+10 = 16
1+(5+10) = 16
1+5+10 = 16
(1+5)+10 = 16
1+(5+10) = 16
1+5-10+19 = 15
(1+5)-10+19 = 15
1+(5-10)+19 = 15
(1+5-10)+19 = 15
1+(5-10+19) = 15
((1+5)-10)+19 = 15
1+((5-10)+19) = 15
(1+(5-10))+19 = 15
1+5-(10-19) = 15
(1+5)-(10-19) = 15
1+(5-(10-19)) = 15
1+5/10*19 = 10.5
(1+5)/10*19 = 11.4
((1+5)/10)*19 = 11.4
(1+5)/(10/19) = 11.4
(1+5)*19/10 = 11.4
(1+5)*(19/10) = 11.399999999999999
((1+5)*19)/10 = 11.4
(5+1)/10*19 = 11.4
((5+1)/10)*19 = 11.4
(5+1)/(10/19) = 11.4
(5+1)*19/10 = 11.4
(5+1)*(19/10) = 11.399999999999999
((5+1)*19)/10 = 11.4
19*(1+5)/10 = 11.4
19*((1+5)/10) = 11.4
(19*(1+5))/10 = 11.4
19*(5+1)/10 = 11.4
19*((5+1)/10) = 11.4
(19*(5+1))/10 = 11.4
19/10*(1+5) = 11.399999999999999
(19/10)*(1+5) = 11.399999999999999
19/(10/(1+5)) = 11.4
19/10*(5+1) = 11.399999999999999
(19/10)*(5+1) = 11.399999999999999
19/(10/(5+1)) = 11.4
```

and shows that the closest we can get is $11.4$ (subject to me being correct about the enumeration!)

*Note to run this in Python 2, change* `for A,B,C,D in permutations((1,5,10,19)):` *to* `for A,B,C,D in permutations((1.,5.,10.,19.)):` *in order to correctly evaluate the floating point arithmetic*

Comment: Excellent _tour de brute force_ (and exhibition of interesting Python utilities)!
I don't see anything missing but do suspect some duplication, as 
`A p B q C`, for instance, seems to be covered by
`(A p B) q C` and
`A p (B q C)`.

Comment: Yes plenty of duplication - note that in your "for instance" not all (`p`, `q`) choices have all three the same, some do, while others have two equal and a third different and some are one pair, while others are another - the duplication just avoids bothering to write complicated code at the expense of more evaluations. (Think `A - B / C` and `A / B - C` and their parenthesised counterparts. EDIT: Maybe the reordering actually takes care of these, um...)

Answer (score 6):

> Turn the 19 upside-down to get 61, subtract 1 to get 60, divide by 10 - 5 to get 12. voilà.

Comment: What about the 10? (Also, I don't think your operation counts under the "subtraction addition multiplication and division" specified in the question.)

Comment: turn that upside-down too, and multiply. he doesn't say we have to use all the numbers - implicitly i guess we should

Comment: @boboquack Not every *short* answer is necessarily a *bad* one.

Comment: If you're going to count an upside down 10 as 1, why not just flip that and subtract 7 from 19?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really mean 19? The order of those numbers looks weird, so I'm wondering if you made a typo and actually mean 1, 5, **9**, 10. If so, the answer is easier:

> $\frac{10}{5}+9+1=12$.

If you really do mean 19 and not 9, then it's harder to get to 12. I've come up with a few possibilities that *almost* work:

- > $\frac{(19+5)\times5}{10}=12$ (uses 5 twice, doesn't use 1)
- > $10+\sqrt{\frac{19+1}{5}}=12$ (uses square root)
- > $10+\frac{19+1}{10}=12$ (uses 10 twice, doesn't use 5)

... and so on, but nothing that *quite* makes it perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add another push-the-envelope answer.

> I haven't found any solution in base 10, but there are solutions when the numbers are in other bases, for example:
>
>     12₁₁ = 19₁₁ + 5₁₁ − 1₁₁ − 10₁₁ = 20 + 5 − 1 − 11 = 13
>     12₁₂ = 1₁₂ × 5₁₂ + 19₁₂ − 10₁₂ = 1 × 5 + 21 − 12 = 14
>     12₁₃ = 1₁₃ + 5₁₃ + 19₁₃ − 10₁₃ = 1 + 5 +22 − 13 = 15
>     12₂₈ = 19₂₈ − 10₂₈ / (5₂₈ − 1₂₈) = 37 − 28 / (5 − 1) = 30
>     12₃₆ = 19₃₆ − (10₃₆ − 1₃₆) / 5₃₆ = 45 − (36 − 1) / 5 = 38
>
>  (Yes, I know that unmarked numbers are in base 10, but it looks as if this question isn't solvable with a bit of lateral thinking.)

Comment: I concur. It is not solvable in base-10. But since base is not specified...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the numbers are 1,5,19,10? I guessing answer was (19/5)+10-1 = 12.8 (or) (5/19)+1*10 = 12.6 by following under conditions (But it's not equal to 12).

we can do like $(5+1+10) - \sqrt{(19+1)/5} = 16-4.36 = 11.64$ (not equal to 12).

I believe $10 + \sqrt{(19+1)/5} = 12$ (need to use Square root)